# Setting package in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way in the Scala REPL to set the "active" package scope ? Say I have a `package com.package` with `class A`, I want to be able to type `new A()` instead of `new com.package.A()` without explicitly doing `import com.package.A`. There might be a number of other classes in that package I'm interested into and I don't want to polute my REPL's global namespace by doing `import com.package._`.

Even better, I'd like to *define* class A without typing its fully qualified name. Something like:

```
package com.package // do this once

class A
class B

val a = new A()
val b = new B()
```

I'm aware of the [`:paste -raw`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/) command, but that would require me to type `package com.package` for each block; I'm really looking for a stateful command to change the "current working package", if you will.

Comment: So, I guess http://stackoverflow.com/a/18510229/6309 wouldn't be helpful either?

Comment: there is currently no support for that because packages are actually used in the internals of the REPL (classes defined in the REPL don't actually live in the root package), but that would make an interesting feature request...

Comment: @VonC: No, this would not allow me to define new classes without a fully qualified name, as per my question.

Comment: Ditto @gourlaysama The use case is testing existing classes with package-private access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use members with default (package) or private access level in REPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685645/how-to-use-members-with-default-package-or-private-access-level-in-repl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot.

Each command in the scala REPL is wrapped into a newly generated package, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685645/how-can-i-use-members-with-default-package-access-level-from-the-scala-repl).

Also, there was [a ticket asking `package { }` support in the REPL](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5299), but it was dismissed as `:paste -raw` was considered enough for the purpose.